# Help Needed with a Limit Problem (L' Hospital's Rule Failed)

Tags: calculus, contest-math, mathematical-physics

Please help me for the limitation below, I tried using L'Hospital's Rule but it seems not to have helped. The square root term at the denominator is repeated after taking derivatives.

\begin{align}
\lim _{\phi\rightarrow\phi_0+\pi} \frac{2j\sin{[ka\sin{(\phi-\phi_0)}}]}{2\sqrt{2}jka\sqrt{1-\sin{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}}
\end{align}
Using L'Hospital rule, one gets
\begin{align}
\lim _{\phi\rightarrow\phi_0+\pi} \frac{2j\cos{[ka\sin{(\phi-\phi_0)}}]ka\cos{(\phi-\phi_0)}}{2\sqrt{2}jka\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}{2\sqrt{1-\sin{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}}}
\end{align}
The norminator is converged to $-2jka$, however the denorminator is in the form of $\frac{0}{0}$, then I continued determining the convergence of the denorminator by using L'Hospital as following

\begin{align}
\lim _{\phi\rightarrow\phi_0+\pi}2\sqrt{2}jka\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}{2\sqrt{1-\sin{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}} = \lim _{\phi\rightarrow\phi_0+\pi}2\sqrt{2}jka \frac{\frac{1}{4}\sin{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}{2\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}{2\sqrt{1-\sin{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}}}
\end{align}
Again, you can see that the term, $\frac{\cos{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-\sin{\frac{\phi-\phi_0}{2}}}}$, is repeated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sometimes you need to use L'Hospital's rule more than once. At each stage, if you get a valid result for the rule (e.g., $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$), you can repeat using the rule to get to the next stage. Did you try L'Hospital's rule just once, or multiple times? Also, please show us your work (by editing the question); it's possible you made a mistake that somebody can point out to you. Also, it'll possibly give us a better idea of how to best help you. Thanks.

Comment: You should note that the denominator is not differentiable at $\phi_0+\pi$.

Comment: I would first simplify the problem a little bit by erasing some irrelevant constants and introducing a new variable:
$$
\lim _{x\to\pi} \frac{\sin{(b\sin{x}})}{\sqrt{2}b\sqrt{1-\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}}
$$

Comment: The limit seems not exist. Where is this problem from?

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the detail of derivation as you recommend John Omielan

Answer (score 1):

Use equivalent infinitesimal. 
Write $\phi-\phi_0$ as $x+\pi$, then $\phi\to\phi_0+\pi\iff x\to0$. Consider what is the equivalent infinitesimal of $\sin[ka\sin(x+\pi)]$? And note that $\sin^2\frac{x}{4}=\frac{1-\cos\frac{x}{2}}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tao X. Your recommend is worked. The result is 2 and that is truely what I am looking for.